# Hierarchical clustering: Should I first normalize / correct for phenotypic data?

Tags: clustering, hierarchical-clustering, bias-correction

I've a set of N=100 samples, each sample having M=10 variables (100x10 matrix). These 10 variables (M_i) are responses to some drugs. In addition I've for each sample a list of phenotype data (categorical and continuous variables) such as age, sex, lympocyte_level, etc..

I would like to perform a hierarchical clustering based on the 100x10 matrix to stratify the 100 samples but I would like to take also into account the phenoytic variables to correct the 10 M_i variables.

Comment: So are these additional variables common to all the samples? So your data is a matrix of dimension 100x(something greater than 10)?

Comment: In fact yes, but I would like to only use the 10 M_i variables for clustering in control of the other phenoytipic data (age, sex, etc...)

Comment: You will have to include these variables into the model in some way for the model to "model" these as well. Why do you not want to include them?

Comment: I want them to be included in the model but in a step before performing the clustering on the corrected M_i

Comment: I don't see how that would be possible. You could use that information to form some sort of structure before hand, based on some procedure, but the model either has the data or it doesn't.